# How to loop multiple Data Tables and Perform print all in same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am having a grid view, in that user can select multiple tests 
with checkBox and finally take print.

I am unable to loop those selected tests in grid view. only 
the first test is printing every time.

**Note:** The Table Columns are static not Dynamic

```
pageload
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grdTests.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)grdTests.Rows[i].FindControl("chkTest");
        Label lblPtestid = (Label)grdTests.Rows[i].FindControl("lbltestid");
        string id= lblPtestid.Text;
        if (chkTest.Checked)
        {
            GetData(id)
            Print()
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
public void GetData(string id)
{
   DataTable dt = Classfile.gettable(id);
   ViewSate["tables"] = dt;
}
public void Print()
{
   ViewSate["tables"].tostring(); //Sample Example
}


public static DataTable gettable(string id)
{
    string Query = "select * from table where id='"+id+"'";
    DataTable dt = DAL.getData(Query);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What do you do in here `Classfile.gettable(id);`? Also just a typo perhaps, you're passing `Label` into `GetData` instead of `string`.

Comment: @Niels Filter: Updated the Question above

Comment: Did you enclosed your code in if(!Page.IsPostback) {} ?

Comment: Ya i enclosed in if(!Page.IsPostback) {}

Comment: Perhaps silly question, but do you select multiple rows in your `gridview`? Also, check how many times your `for` loop iterates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting data for each selected record, why not 'get all' data at once and print a single data table which you are already doing. This also saves you hitting database for each selected record.

```
string csvId = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < grdTests.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)grdTests.Rows[i].FindControl("chkTest");
    Label lblPtestid = (Label)grdTests.Rows[i].FindControl("lbltestid");
    string id= lblPtestid.Text;
    if (chkTest.Checked)
    {
        csvId += id + ",";
        // GetData(id)
        // Print()
    }
    else {} // This is not required actually.
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvId))
{
    // Trim the extra comma at the end.
    csvId = csvId.Remove(csvId.Length - 1);

    // Get data for all selected records.
    GetData(csvId);
    Print();
}

public static DataTable gettable(string id)
{
    string Query = "select * from table where id IN ('" + id + "')";
    DataTable dt = DAL.getData(Query);
    return dt;
}
```

Note the IN clause used in select query in 'gettable' method.